# how to retrieve media information without using IMediaDet interface?

Tags: winapi, video, directshow

I need to get the framerate and the duration of the media for an application which uses VMR9. But ImediaDet cannot be used with d3d9. Are there any alternative interfaces for IMediaDet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Media Detector (MediaDet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has nothing to do with D3D9 and still can be used (note it's deprecated though). As an alternate method, you can render your source to [Null Renderer(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check media types on filters added through [Intelligent Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Those video media types will give you what you look for.

Answer (score 1):

I asked MS for alternatives, while  the suggested Null Renderer and all other render methodes based on Intelligent Connect are deprecated too.